# How to assign a value to an embedded message field in Protocol buffer Python

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, message

I have following proto and I am trying to assign a value to an embedded message field

```
message Foo {
  required Bar bar = 1;
}
message Bar {
  optional int32 i = 1;
}
```

When I am writing following code in python, It gives below error

```
foo = Foo()
foo.bar.i = 1
```

Error:

> AttributeError: 'instancemethod' object has no attribute 'i'

How to deal with this error?

Comment: `bar` is a method. what happens when you call it i.e. `bar()`

Answer (score 0):

To do what you want, in Python, you have to define the `bar` method within the `Foo` class. Something like this will do it:

```
class Foo:
    i = 1

    def bar(self):
        return self.i

if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo = Foo()
    foo.bar = 1
    print(foo.bar)  # this will print 1
```

Comment: def bar(self): is already exists. However I am still facing same err...